# I am trying to understand how to fill in the rest of the positions in matrix $A$.

Tags: matrices

[image]

I am trying to understand how to fill in the rest of the positions in matrix $A$.

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}3&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\1&3&1&0&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&1&3&1&0&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&1&3&1&0&0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&1&3&1&0&0&0&0 \\0&0&0&0&1&3&1&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0&0&1&3&1&0&0 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&1&0 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3&1 \\0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&1&3\end{bmatrix}$$

Am I correct with my implementation above?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how I would interpret it too.